# Cocoa/Finder: weird path

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, path, finder, scripting-bridge

im asking the finder for the current finder window location/path/whatever with

```
NSString *path = [[finder insertionLocation] get];
```

which results in a path like that:

```
2011-06-03 18:38:55.132 CutIt[1980:903] <FinderFolder @0x1561d960: FinderFolder "eike" of FinderFolder "Users" of startupDisk of application "Finder" (185)>
```

is there a common way to convert that into a usable path, like `/users/eike`, or do i have to patch something together myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit nested, but you can divide it as you like:

```
NSString *path = [[NSURL URLWithString:[[[finder insertionLocation] get] URL]] path];
```

Comment: thanks that works, although xcode warns me about incompatible pointers

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested, here's a way to get the path without the casting warning:

```
NSURL *insertLocation = [[[finder insertionLocation] get] URL];
NSString *path = [[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",insertLocation]] path];
```